# Attachments from sendgrid are saved but empty

Tags: python, flask, request, python-3.7, sendgrid

With this code I'm trying to save files attached to emails send to sendgrid.io
It's running og pythonanywhere, and I can se in the accesslog, that my endpoint is beeing hit by a post request from sendgrid.

Only an empty file is saved, and I get no errors in the error log.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class newEmail(Resource):
    def post(self):
        num_attachments = int(request.form.get('attachments', 0))
        attachments = []
        if num_attachments > 0:
            for num in range(1, (num_attachments + 1)):
                attachment = request.files.get(('attachment%d' % num))
                attachments.append(attachment.read())
                attachment.save('test.pdf')
        return 'OK'

api.add_resource(newEmail, '/')
```

Comment: What do you get when you print out `attachment.read()`

Comment: I get this ; b''

Comment: What about printing `request.files.keys()`?  Maybe there are multiple attachments?

Comment: I ask sendgrid. The attachment it self is not send. Only meta data. Sorry for the trouble.